# Always show greater margin

Tags: html, css, margins

I have given one block a bottom margin of 25px and a top margin of 10px. The total margin should then be 35px but it is showing 25px. If I give 35px margin, then it shows the total of 35px. Why is it showing greater margin always?

Here are the code lines:

```
<p style="margin-bottom:25px; outline:1px dashed #000000;">aaaaaaaaaaaa</P>
<p style="margin-top:10px; outline:1px dashed #000000;">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it i showing 25px". How do you see those 25px?

Comment: @FaisalAkhter If one of the answers helped you, then please consider marking one as answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's called "collapsing margins". This is normal, and is in accordance with the W3 standards. It says:

> - Margins of the root element's box do not collapse.
> - If the top and bottom margins of an element with clearance are
>     adjoining, its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of
>     following siblings but that resulting margin does not collapse with
>     the bottom margin of the parent block.

**More info:**
 http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Therefore your two `<p>` tags:

```
<p style="margin-bottom:25px; outline:1px dashed #000000;">aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p style="margin-top:10px; outline:1px dashed #000000;">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
```

would then collapse.

The specifications also mention cases where margins are not collapsed. For example, floated elements have non-collapsed margins:

> Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse

And a fiddle demonstrating collapsed and non-collapsed margins:

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/k8tFy/3/
*(Note: you can even see the floated `<p>` tag is even interacting with the `margin-bottom` of the `<h2>` tag)*

Comment: What? "Adjoining margins" are margins that touch or intersect each other - the statement that prefaces the bullet list that you quote says precisely that adjoining vertical margins collapse by definition, with those cases listed as exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Updating my answer now, the "adjoining margins" (which is what I've been calling it =/) is the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2):

If short, that is how margins should work. Top and bottom margins may collapse and in that case final distance between two blocks will be equal to the width of largest margin.

For more details take a look at this part of CSS standart:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

> When two or more margins collapse, the resulting margin width is the
>   maximum of the collapsing margins' widths.

Possible solutions:
You may simply put margin-bottom of top element to 35px, just like you described.

Another way is to make one of elements to be float:

```
<p style="margin-bottom:25px; outline:1px dashed #000000;clear:both;">aaaaaaaaaaaa</P>
<p style="margin-top:10px; outline:1px dashed #000000;clear:both;float:left;width:100%">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YzWrF/)

Above solution based on next exception you may find on page linked above:

> Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not
>   even between a float and its in-flow children).